# Need to break up and get values using String Manupulation

Tags: java, string, graph, string-matching

I need to draw a dynamic graph i.e. monitoring a Linux machine Server. Below is the result output of the Linux machine server, using this I will draw a graph.

`02:54:09 PM kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit
02:54:11 PM    143612   3678012     96.24    217016   2067000   3024356     37.73
02:54:13 PM    143612   3678012     96.24    217016   2067000   3024356     37.73
02:54:15 PM    143612   3678012     96.24    217016   2067000   3024356     37.73
02:54:17 PM    143488   3678136     96.25    217016   2067000   3024356     37.73
02:54:19 PM    143488   3678136     96.25    217016   2067000   3024356     37.73
02:54:21 PM    143488   3678136     96.25    217016   2067000   3024356     37.73
02:54:23 PM    143488   3678136     96.25    217016   2067000   3024356     37.73
02:54:25 PM    143488   3678136     96.25    217016   2067000   3024356     37.73
02:54:27 PM    143488   3678136     96.25    217016   2067000   3024356     37.73
02:54:29 PM    143488   3678136     96.25    217016   2067000   3024356     37.73
02:54:31 PM    143488   3678136     96.25    217016   2067000   3024356     37.73
02:54:33 PM    143488   3678136     96.25    217016   2067000   3024356     37.73`

My problem is, **I need to get the values of “%memused” Column (96.24 value column I need to get).**

I tried to separate **them using the string positions but failed** to get correct values as the value length changes frequently which lead me to **fatal ERROR**. Can anyone suggest any logic for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
try {
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
          (new FileInputStream("pathofthtextfile")));
       while(true) {
          String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
          if (line == null) {
                break;
          }
          else{
             String[] data = line.split("\\s+");
             System.out.println(data[4]);
          }
}

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to replace white space on a line with a single delimer, comma or pipe. 
Then you should successfully be able to use the String.split(String regex) to successfully parse the line.